# How to access values from object

Tags: python, datetime

I don't know ho to even ask but essentially I want to use the values in this output from a datetime object.

```
time.struct_time(tm_year=2019, tm_mon=5, tm_mday=12, tm_hour=13, tm_min=30, tm_sec=19, tm_wday=6, tm_yday=132, tm_isdst=1)
```

and compare them with an `if` statement using `(y,d,h)`.

I lack the vocabulary to look for it. I don't know for certain what the first output is called is an object tuple etc. Some clarification or a link to the documentation might be nice.

Comment: So you want to compare the year, date and hour parts of the timestamp 2019-05-12 13:30:19 (or presumably any timestamp) with something?

Comment: `if tm_year == y:`

Comment: So essentially I want compare the stuff inside the the tuple with the output above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
     import time
     seconds = time.time();
     result = time.ctime(seconds);

     if(result.tm_year==y &&result.tm_mday==d &&result.tm_hour==h)
     {
     }
```

Something like this?

Answer (score 0):

You can represent the parts you want as a tuple, and then compare these tuples:

```
import time

t1 = time.localtime()
time.sleep(1)
t2 = time.localtime()

a = t1.tm_year, t1.tm_mday, t1.tm_hour
b = t2.tm_year, t2.tm_mday, t2.tm_hour

print("a={}, b={}".format(a, b))
if a == b:
    print("They are the same.")
else:
    print("Different year, day or hour.")
```

Obviously, the example above will only print that they are different if you time that `time.sleep(1)` to run exactly across a boundary between hours, days or years. I just did that for demontration purposes.